# JTextField expands vertically in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, boxlayout

If in BoxLayout and FlowLayout each component gets its preferred size, why when adding a JTextField to a JPanel using BoxLayout make it stretch vertically if it is only a "one-liner"?

```
public void go() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextField field = new JTextField();

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(field);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,panel);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

The width of the text field is okay but why does it stretch vertically if it is definitely not the preferred height? JButtons don't behave like this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the preferred size? You might also try setting the maximum size to that preferred size. From the docs:

> `BoxLayout` pays attention to a component's requested minimum, preferred, and maximum sizes.

You can use `.setMaximumSize()` with BoxLayout to prevent it from stretching to fit. Or, you could use `GridBagLayout`, which can be a little tricky, but gives you more power.

```
// Setting sizes
comp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
comp.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
```

Comment: I'm not setting a preferred size. Does this mean that the BoxLayout uses the maximumSize of the component AS the preferredSize by default?

Comment: @vader not necessarily. For example, if you have two components within some panel, both components *together* will fill the entire panel - but they won't *both* be the same size of the panel (they would not fit) - they would be roughly half the size.

Comment: If instead of adding a JTextField to the example above I add two JButtons, they do not fill up the entire panel. How come the JTextField does?

Comment: *I'm not setting a preferred size.* - all Swing components determine their own "preferred size" and "maximum size" and the two sizes can be different. *I add two JButtons, they do not fill up the entire panel.* - the "maximumSize" of the JButton is the same as its "preferredSize" so the buttons won't grow. The text field maximum size is set to Integer.MAX, so the text field will grow to take up the extra space.

Comment: If you don't want the component to grow, then don't use random numbers. Instead you would use `component.setMaximumSize( component.getPreferredSize() )`. This assumes the preferred size of the component never changes. It the size does change, then you should be overriding the `getMaximumSize()` method of the component to return the `getPreferredSize()`.